# Can we connect to other database on another host in django

Tags: python, database, django, connection

Hi i need to fetch data from another database which is on another host and insert into local database , is it possible to connect two databases at a time

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. Please have a look at the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/).