# Is it possible that we can connect to multiple databases in django at one time

Tags: python, mysql, django, settings

I am migrating some data from one database to another (`db1` --> `db2`). The `db1` is in a host and `db2` is at another (so, the databases are in different hosts). I have to select data from `db1` and insert into `db2`. 
As we can make multiple connections in PHP in any .php file , but in django we make the connection in `settings.py` file, so I am afraid whether I can do this in `django` or not.

If yes,then please suggest me the way to do this.

Thanks !!

**Edit :**

Suppose I made connection like this

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'acd',
        'PASSWORD': 'aaa'
        "HOST": "host1",
        "PORT": "port1",
    },
    'users': {
        'NAME': 'app_data1',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'sdfa'
        "HOST": "host1",
        "PORT": "port1",
    }
}
```

As there are different hosts and port no for both connections, as mentioned in docs it will make the connections.

But I want to use raw sql queries so how I mentioned which sql query connect to which db, I have mentioned some code will it work ??

```
for db1  --  Author.objects.db_manager('app_data').raw('some query')
for db2  --- Author.objects.db_manager('app_data1').raw('some query')
```

Comment: asked minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722116/can-we-connect-to-other-database-on-another-host-in-django

Comment: a google search or browsing the django docs might help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: I read the docs but I am worry about couple of things, I have edit my question please look at that.

Comment: have you tried anything in the shell?  like Author.objects.using("users").raw("some query")

Comment: No not yet , it gives me internal server while i define the settings for multiple db

Comment: Now i have tried and it works i have used this `cursor = connections['migration'].cursor()` instead of  `Author.objects.using("users").raw("some query")`